# Move my project from public_html/web to public_html

Tags: 8, composer

I have a Drupal site installed via composer, creating a structure like

```
vendor/
config/
composer.json
etc/
web/core
web/themes
web/index.php
web/etc
```

Is there a way to change the `web` folder to a `public_html` folder so I can use it on my hosting? So the structure needs to be:

```
vendor/
config/
composer.json
etc/
public_html/core
public_html/themes
public_html/index.php
public_html/etc
```

I got it working now by using .htaccess but I started using this method with the config outside of my root folder because of the security advantages. With this method, the config is still in my root but via htaccess I point everybody to the web folder. Is this still secure enough?

So how can I change this and is it necessary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to change the installer paths in `composer.json`, which defines where the files are placed:

```
"installer-paths": {
  "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
  "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
  "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
  "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
  "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
},
```

to:

```
"installer-paths": {
  "public_html/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
  "public_html/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
  "public_html/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
  "public_html/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
  "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
},
```

You can then rename the `web` folder to `public_html` and everything should work.

Comment: I don't know if it was necessary but I did a composer update after the change. But it works perfectly!

Comment: I tried this, but I reinstalled had to change a line in scripts/ as well.

Comment: When changing the paths on an existing installation, use `composer dump-autoload` for updating the autoload files to make it work once the paths are changed.

Answer (score 2):

The steps to install Drupal in public_html is to make a 'modified install', this means initiating your project with this `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project my_site_name_dir --no-interaction --no-install`This will initiate Drupal 9, if you want Drupal 8 instead then use this `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:^8 my_site_name_dir --no-interaction --no-install`

The `--no-install` flag will stop the installation of Drupal upon project initiation.

You should be in your Cpanel root (one step away from public_html), this will initiate your project inside `my_site_name_dir` directory. Cd into the directory and move composer.json and composer.lock up inside the Cpanel root, move back to the root and delete the now empty `my_site_name_dir` directory.

Open composer.json in an editor and change the web-root and installer-paths from 'web/' to 'public_html/', save the file and from Cpanel root run `composer install`.

Drupal will be installed inside public_html and you can access your site on site.com without any sub-directories. Also vendor folder and the Composer files will be placed away from your web-root (public_html) which is the recommended setup.

I explain this also in my blog post, https://www.skillmaticace.com/blog/how-install-drupal-8-composer-cpanel

Comment: very useful answer to the question